# Using a Recursive CTE in SQL to get Cost Per Lbs

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am a pretty decent C# programmer, and have a lot of experience in T-SQL, but I am having trouble putting together a recursive CTE to solve my problem.

I need to get the Cost per Lbs of a Recipe.

Recipes are made up of Ingredients, but Ingredients can also be other Recipes.  In the Ingredient table, there is a field called associatedProductID.  If it is null then we just use the CostPerLb of that Ingredient (which is found by getting the latest IngredientStock CostPerLb.  If it is not null then that Ingredient is actually another Recipe, and we need to first find the Cost per lbs of that other recipe.  Then we sum up the total Cost of that Ingredient (Quantity of the Ingredient used in the Recipe * costPerLb of that ingredient)  and then finally divide by the total Lbs of the Recipe to get CostPerLbl of the Recipe

Here is some simplified table info.

- table [*Recipes*] has an int **ID**
- table [*RecipeIngredints*] has int **RecipeID**, int **IngredientID**, decimal **Quantity**
- table [*Ingredients*] has int **ID**, int **AssociatedProductID**
- table [*IngredientStock*] has int **ID**, int **IngredientID**, decimal **CostPerLb**

example data:

```
[Recipes]
+------+
| ID   |
+------+
| 11   |
+------+
| 465  |
+------+
| 356  |
+------+
| 1617 |
+------+

[Ingredients]
+--------------+--------------------+
| IngredientID | AssociatedPrductId |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 213          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 214          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 216          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 218          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 219          | 465                |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 225          | 356                |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 150          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 213          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 692          | 1617               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 172          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 218          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 4            | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 691          | NULL               |
+--------------+--------------------+

[RecipeIngredients]
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| RecipeID | IngredientID | Quanity     |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 213          | 2           |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 214          | 1           |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 216          | 4.31494     |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 218          | 10.4125     |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 219          | 10.37085    |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 11       | 225          | 3.141971875 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 465      | 150          | 0.0995      |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 465      | 213          | 0.25        |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 465      | 692          | 6.752298547 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 356      | 172          | 200         |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 356      | 218          | 249.9       |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 1617     | 4            | 26.59274406 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
| 1617     | 691          | 0.743192188 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

In my head, a generic recursive function might look like this... (this obviously isn't a CTE and also doesn't work....)

```
 FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs]
 (@ID INT = 0)
RETURNS DECIMAL(24,12)
AS
BEGIN select
 sum(
        --get the actual amount of ingredient used in the recipe (in lbs)
        ri.Quantity

        --get the cost of the ingredient (in $ / lbs)
        case 
          --when associated product id is null then use the latest ingredient stock cost / lbs
          --when its not null then use the cost / lbs of the recipe that it relates too
        when  i.AssociatedProductID is null then 
            --pull the cost/lbs of the newest stock in warehouse
            isNull((select top 1 ist.CostPerLb from IngredientStock ist where ist.IngredientID = i.id order by ist.id desc),0)
        else
            [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs](@ID)
        end
    )
    / 
    dbo.fn_FunctionToGetTotalRecipeLbs(@ID) -- divide by total lbs of the recipe to get cost Per Lbs
    as CostPerLbs


from RecipeIngredients ri
inner join Ingredients i on i.id = ri.IngredientID
where ri.RecipeID = @ID
)
```

Thanks in advance!

-David

Comment: the way you've described your tables - it seems like a recipe is made from a list of ingredients (RecipeIngredints), and the the cost of these (I'm guessing) is held in Ingredients and IngredientStock - could you link the 4 tables together and summarise  Quantity * CostPerLb

Comment: I realise that you say 'ingredients can be a recipe' - how is that catered for in your tables though?

Comment: Having some tables and sample data would go a long way to improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Also, those scalar function can cause you some serious performance problems. Scalar function are notoriously poor performers. The way you are calling them here means they run once for every single row.

Comment: Andrew, in the Ingredients table, there is a field called AssociatedProductID.  (as explained in the question) if this is not null, then the ingredient actually refers to another recipe.  Much like a bill of materials would be a list of products...but there could be another assembly (bill of matierals) referenced as a product on a bill of materails

Comment: Sean, thanks for the comment. This query was meant to be a the function: [fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs] (thus making it recursive)...but it was only hypothetical... and the fn_FunctionToGetTotalRecipeLbs is only called once after the sum. My intention is to not use the query above at all..but to get help building a CTE.

Comment: I think you need to approach it differently -

Use the CTE to get a list of all the actual ingredients in the recipe with quantities, then join the results of the CTE to get the costs.

Comment: FJT, yes that woudl work, then I could do all the calculations on the resulting tableset.  Still working on that though.  If I just had a table with fields [recipeid, ingredientid, quantity, associatedproductId] could you give me an example of  flattening this with a CTE?

Comment: See my example of a recursive CTE, but I think we are lacking a worked example here, how is the cost per pound of a sub-recipe determined?  if there is a simple example, like 'stew' and it's made of meat and gravy - so meat is a basic ingredient with cost 10 and quantity 5, and gravy is a recipe with quantity 8 and it is made of 2 x water (cost per lb = 1) and 1 x flavouring (cost per lb=25) - what does that make the result you want?

Comment: Andrew,  the cost per lbs is found by looking up the last entered ingredient_stock in inventory.  unless the ingredient has an associated product. then the ingredient cost per lbs would be the cost per lbs of the associated prouduct.  which is why we need recursion. ... In your example, im assuming you meant that meat cost 10/lbs.  This makes the Stew's total weight of 13Lbs.  The water weights 5.33 lbs (costs 5.33 total) and the flavor weighs 2.66lbs (costs 66.67)  brining the total cost to about $122 at about $9.4 / lbs.   I couldn't get your answer to work just yet

Comment: you needed to give a much clearer example from the start, and explain all your tables and fields - you'd have been better to have given a script to build and populate a set of sample tables

Answer (score 0):

since you can use a recursive function in SQL, use one something like this - if the associate product ID is NOT NULL, then call the query to evaluate its cost - probably dividing/multiplying the cost per pound by something in the CASE statement

This is a recursive function, as opposed to a recursive CTE

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs]
 (@ID INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(24,12)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @COST DECIMAL(24,12) = 0;


SELECT @COST = SUM(CASE WHEN IngredientStock.AssociatedProductID IS NULL 
                                                    THEN 
                                                        IngredientStock.CostPerLb 
                                                    ELSE  
                                                        [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs](IngredientStock.AssociatedProductID)
                                                    END
                    )

                                     FROM RecipeIngredints  
                                      join Ingredients 
                                         on RecipeIngredints.RecipeID = @ID 
                                        AND 
                                        Ingredients.id = RecipeIngredints.IngredientID
                                     join IngredientStock 
                                         on 
                                         IngredientStock.ID = Ingredients.AssociatedProductID

    RETURN @COST;

)
```

I guess also you might need to find the total cost and the total weight of each recipe, then return total cost/total weight - but that should be possible

edit

maybe something like -

Are you familiar with joins between tables?  I'm not sure how your tables are designed to link together - you might have to make changes, or give more information - a good way to do that is to give a script to make a small set of sample tables (try and cut out unnecessary fields id there are too many of them) and give a small amount of representitive data

```
SELECT @COST = SUM(RecipeIngredints.Quantity * (CASE WHEN Ingredients.AssociatedProductID IS NULL 
                                                    THEN 
                                                        IngredientStock.CostPerLb 
                                                    ELSE  
                                                        [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerLbs](IngredientStock.AssociatedProductID)
                                                    END) )/ SUM(RecipeIngredints.Quantity)


                                     FROM RecipeIngredints  
                                      join Ingredients 
                                         on RecipeIngredints.RecipeID = @ID 
                                        AND 
                                        Ingredients.id = RecipeIngredints.IngredientID
                                     join IngredientStock 
                                         on 
                                         IngredientStock.ID = Ingredients.AssociatedProductID
```

Comment: Andrew please see my response to the post.  This query you gave doesn't work and isn't really close to how the tables work.  the IngredientStock table has a forienKey of ingredientID that links it back.  and the AssociatedProductID is on the Ingredient table not the stock table...and links the ingredient back to the Recipe.  (product and recipe are the same here) ... Lastly you are correct that I need the total weight of the product and then to divide that by the cost of the ingredients. which is determined by the cost per lbs of the ingredients multiplied by the RecipeIngrediet.Quanity

Comment: @Javadave - have you tried changing the table name for AssociatedProductID?  I don't think I could do much more than sketch up a general idea, because we didn't have all the calculation formulae   you wanted to use - try the function on a basic recipe with no sub-recipes - i'll try to make it average the weight/cost

Comment: Are you able to write SQL to do this if you assumed that a recipe is only made of basic ingredients?  I think that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. If anyone wants to improve on this please let me know... Thanks for the help thought.  Also this responds in 8ms so better than my C#/EF 2 SEC each.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getRecipeCostPerPound]
(
@ID INT = 0
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(24,12)
AS
BEGIN

Declare @Ret decimal(24,12) = 0;
Declare @TotalLbs decimal(24,12) =  [dbo].[fn_RecipeLbs](@ID)


    DECLARE @MyCTETempTable TABLE (RecipeID int,
    IngredientID int,
    AssociatedProductID int,
    Quantity decimal(24,12),
    level int,
    CostPerLbs decimal(24,12)
    )


; with  CTE as 
        (
            select  
              ri.RecipeID
              ,ri.IngredientID
              ,i.AssociatedProductID
             ,dbo.fn_ConvertUomToPounds(ri.Quantity,ri.UnitOfMeasureID,i.specificgravity) as Quantity
              ,1 as level
            from    RecipeIngredients ri inner join Ingredients i on i.id = ri.IngredientID 
            where   ri.RecipeID = @ID
            union all
            select  
               ri_child.RecipeID
              ,ri_child.IngredientID
              ,i_child.AssociatedProductID
              ,dbo.fn_ConvertUomToPounds(ri_child.Quantity,ri_child.UnitOfMeasureID,i_child.specificgravity) as Quantity
              ,level + 1
            from     RecipeIngredients ri_child inner join Ingredients i_child on i_child.id = ri_child.IngredientID --and i_child.AssociatedProductID is null
            join    CTE parent
            on      parent.AssociatedProductID = ri_child.RecipeID
        )

INSERT INTO @MyCTETempTable (
RecipeID,
IngredientID,
AssociatedProductID,
Quantity,
level,
CostPerLbs
)  

select 
cte.*,  isNull((select top 1 ist.CostPerLb from IngredientStock ist where ist.IngredientID = cte_i.id order by ist.id desc),0) 
from    CTE
inner join Ingredients cte_i on cte_i.id = CTE.IngredientID

SET @Ret = (select sum(Quantity * CostPerLbs) / @TotalLbs
from @MyCTETempTable tt 
where RecipeID = @ID
group by RecipeID)



return @Ret

END
```